# Behaviour of $f(x)=e-\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^{x}$ when $x\to+\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

This is from an MCQ contest.

> For all $x\geq 1$ let  $f(x)=e-\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x} \right)^{x}$ then we have :
>
> 1. $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{\sim}}\dfrac{e}{x}$ and $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty[$
> 2. $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{\sim}}\dfrac{e}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $f$ is not integrable on $[1,+\infty[$
> 3. $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{\sim}}\dfrac{e}{\sqrt{2}x}$ and $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty[$
> 4. $f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{\sim}}\dfrac{e}{2x}$ and $f$ is not integrable on $[1,+\infty[$

My thoughts :

i don't know how to prove that for example to show that a is true shall we procced like this 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{e-e^{ x\ln(1+\dfrac{1}{x}) } }{ \dfrac{e}{x}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left( 1-e^{x\ln(1+\dfrac{1}{x})}\right)$$

Comment: Along the lines of your idea, we have $(1+1/x)^x=e^{x \ln(1+1/x)}=e^{x(1/x-1/2x^2+o(1/x^2))}=e^{1-1/2x+o(1/x)}=e(e^{-1/2x+o(1/x)})$. So $f(x)=e(1-e^{-1/2x+o(1/x)})$. Can you work with this?

Comment: 1. and 3. can be excluded *a priori*, because if $f(x)\sim k/x$ then $f$ cannot be integrable on $[1,+\infty[$.

Comment: i think your expression its expansion in the neighborhood of zero. not on $+\infty$

Comment: @Educ If $x$ is very large then $1/x$ is very small, so the expansion is correct. It also gives answer #4 when you simplify.

Comment: @Ian could u provide ur detailed answer with calculation  thank u

Comment: @Educ I think you can handle the next step, which is just Taylor expanding $e^{-1/2x+o(1/x)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers 1. and 3. can be excluded *a priori*, because if $f(x)\sim k/x$ then $f$ cannot be integrable on $[1,+\infty[$.

Then it is quite obvious that we can make a Taylor expansion in $1/x$, which will never yield a $\sqrt{x}$ term: if so 2. can be excluded and the correct answer should be 4.

In fact, using $\ln(1+t)=t-t^2/2+O(t^3)$ one gets
$$
e-e^{x\ln(1+1/x)}=e - e^{1-1/(2x)+O(1/x^2)}=
e\left(1-e^{-1/(2x)+O(1/x^2)}\right)=e\left({1\over2x}+O\left({1\over x^2}\right)\right).
$$

Comment: Ho do you know it will become a Taylor expansion in $1/x$? It can a priori be any form of asymptotic expansion.

Comment: thank u but could u just give more detailed for $2$ as Ian did

Comment: @DanielFischer I've relaxed a bit my bold statement. I was just showing the kind of reasoning one may use during a contest, when a quick answer is needed.

Comment: Well done. A +1

Comment: Well-explained A+1 too